# How can I use the PDO support in my own php extension?

Tags: c, pdo, php-extension

I want to use PDO MySQL in my php extension(use c language, not simple pdo wrapper class in php), but I have no idea about this case, anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you plan to do with PDO in your extension? It's primarily intended as a service for PHP code, not for other extensions.

Comment: check http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/

Comment: Thanks Steven Farley for a tag modify, yes it written in c.

Comment: @duskwuff I want make a access control, its security, so cannot use PHP code for it.

Comment: thanks @NullPointer for tag modified

Comment: @user1891502: Wait, what? That's no reason to go writing a PHP extension.

Comment: I solved it, just use zend_call_method. here is a sample
http://zoeeyphp.googlecode.com/hg/src/recorder.c
google search "pdo zend_call_method" may find some articles about it.

Comment: @user1891502 you should write an answer based on your solution and accept it, that way this will be of future use to other people as well

Comment: @Jasper Yes, now I'm gathering some materials for this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was solved by google, follow this guide may solved your problem, it can be used in other zend classes.

Note: The basic concepts about **how to create a php extension in c** is needed.

1.You need to patch the origin zend_call_method, because the origin zend_call_method
**only support less than 3 argument**, and PDO's constructor use 1-4 args.

> PDO::__construct() ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $driver_options ]]] )

Find "zend_interfaces.c" in your php source directory(maybe in "php-5.x.x-src\Zend\zend_interfaces.c"), target to "zend_call_method" part, copy it paste into your code and do like this:

> ```
> /* {{{ zend_call_method
>  Only returns the returned zval if retval_ptr != NULL */
> ZEND_API zval* zend_call_method_n_params(
>   zval **object_pp, zend_class_entry *obj_ce,
>   zend_function **fn_proxy, const char *function_name,
>   int function_name_len, zval **retval_ptr_ptr,
>   int param_count, zval *** params TSRMLS_DC)
> // ↑↑↑new function definition
> // only change "zval* arg1, zval* arg2" to "zval *** params"
> // make a new function name "zend_call_method_n_params"
> {
>         ...
>
>   //zval **params[2];            ← delete it!
>   //params[0] = &arg1;           ← delete it!
>   //params[1] = &arg2;           ← delete it! done.
>
>         ...
> }
> /* }}} */
> ```

Note: You may need some macros:

```
#define call_method(obj, obj_ce, fn_proxy, function_name, retval, param_count, params) \
    zend_call_method_n_params(obj, obj_ce, fn_proxy, function_name, sizeof(function_name)-1, retval, param_count, params TSRMLS_CC)

#define call_function(function_name, retval, param_count, params) \
    zend_call_method(NULL, NULL, NULL, function_name, retval, param_count, params)

#define call_construct(obj, obj_ce, param_count, params) \
    call_method(obj, obj_ce, &obj_ce->constructor, obj_ce->constructor->common.function_name, NULL, param_count, params)
```

2.hello world!

Setup your code, we need a property "pdo"

```
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(yourextension)
{
    ...
    zend_declare_property_null(you_class_entry, ZEND_STRL("pdo"),
                               ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
    ...
}
```

> ```
> PHP_METHOD(foo, bar)
> {
>     char * dsn = "mysql:dbname=yourdb;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306";
>     char * usr = "username";
>     char * pwd = "password";
>     zval * zdsn = NULL;
>     zval * zusr = NULL;
>     zval * zpwd = NULL;
>
>     zval ** params[3];
>     zend_class_entry * pdo_class_entry;
>
>     if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "") == FAILURE) {
>         RETURN_FALSE;
>     }
>
>     // get class entry for PDO
>     pdo_class_entry = zend_fetch_class(ZEND_STRL("PDO"),
>                                    ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_AUTO TSRMLS_CC);
>
>     // initial PDO instance
>     MAKE_STD_ZVAL(pdo_inst);
>     object_init_ex(pdo_inst, pdo_class_entry);
>
>     // arg1: dns string
>     ALLOC_INIT_ZVAL(zdns);
>     ZVAL_STRINGL(zdsn, dsn, sizeof(dsn)-1, 1);
>
>     // arg2: username
>     ALLOC_INIT_ZVAL(zusr);
>     ZVAL_STRINGL(zusr, usr, sizeof(usr)-1, 1);
>
>     // arg3: password
>     ALLOC_INIT_ZVAL(zpwd);
>     ZVAL_STRINGL(zpwd, pwd, sizeof(pwd)-1, 1);
>
>     // put them in params array
>     params[0] = &zdsn;
>     params[1] = &zusr;
>     params[2] = &zpwd;
>
>     // call PDO::__construct(zdns, zusr, zpwd)
>     zend_call_method_n_params(&pdo_inst,
>         pdo_class_entry,
>         &pdo_class_entry->constructor,
>         ZEND_STRL(pdo_class_entry->constructor->common.function_name),
>         NULL, 3,    // 3 params
>         params TSRMLS_CC);
>     // or simply use macro instead()
>     //call_construct(&pdo_inst, pdo_class_entry,3,params);
>     if (pdo_inst && Z_TYPE_P(pdo_inst) == IS_OBJECT) {
>         zend_update_property(your_class_entry, getThis(),
>                              ZEND_STRL("pdo") , pdo_inst TSRMLS_CC);
>         zend_printf("Success.\n");
>     } else {
>         zend_printf("Failure.\n");
>     }
> }
> ```

In php can call like this:

```
$foo = new foo();
$foo->bar(); // connect by PDO and update $foo->pdo
// you can use pdo property now
var_dump($foo->pdo->query("select * from table")->fetchAll());
```

It works fine. Cheers!